# Dynamic binding of a filter in Jersey doesn't work for sub-resources

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I created a Jersey filter and I need it assigned to some resources (not all). Therefore, I'm using dynamic binding to achieve that.

```
public class MyDynamicFeature implements DynamicFeature {

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceInfo resourceInfo, FeatureContext featureContext) {
        Path resourcePath = resourceInfo.getResourceClass().getAnnotation(Path.class);
        if (resourcePath != null && resourcePath.value().contains("/v2/"))
        {
            featureContext.register(MyFilter.class);
        }
    }
}
```

So I want this filter to be applied to all methods in those resources that contain a certain string in their paths. Some of those resources use sub-resource locators to define sub-resources. E.g.,

```
@Path("/v2/resource_path")
@Consumes({ ... })
@Produces({ ... })
class MyResource 
{
    @Path("/subresource_path")
    public MySubResource getSubResource(@Context ResourceContext rc)
    {
        return rc.getResource(MySubResource.class);
    }   
}
```

Even though Jersey documentation claims

> The configure method will be executed once for each resource method that is defined in the application.

the `configure` method in `MyDynamicFeature` shown above doesn't get called for `getSubResource` method of `MyResource` class at all. It does get called for all the rest of the methods in `MyResource` class though (which I omitted in the example).

Is there a way to make this work for sub-resources? I need my filter to be applied to `MySubResource` as well.

We use Jersey 2.21.

Comment: Becuase the `@Path` for `getSubResource` is `/subresource_path` and therefore does NOT contain `v2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out [this issue](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_RS_SPEC-334). I'm not sure that it is currently possible. If you add some logging in your feature to log the method and class, you will see that subresource methods are never traversed. As explained by Marek in the issue, it's because in order to handle this, the sub-resource locator method would need to be invoked, which it never is.

The only workaround is to use [`Name Binding`](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9988) instead. I've tested this and it works (see below). The idea is to make a custom annotation, and annotate the filter, the resource class, and sub-resource class you want filtered. For example

```
@NameBinding
@Target({METHOD, TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SomeAnno {}

@SomeAnno
public class Filter implements ContainerRequestFilter {}

@SomeAnno
@Path("v2")
public class V2Resource {

    @Path("sub")
    public V2SubResource get()  {
        return new V2SubResource();
    }

    @SomeAnno
    public static class V2SubResource {
        @GET
        public String get() { return "get"; }
    }
}
```

The above would bind all the resource methods in `V2Resource` as well as `V2SubResource`.

Below is a complete example using [Jersey Test Framework](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/test-framework.html). Run it like any other JUnit test

**UPDATE**: Note that with the below tests, with the current (2.26) version of Jersey, the tests for the version 2 resource hangs because of the 1000 status code being returned in the filter. I guess Jersey doesn't like this. To fix this just change the status code in the filter to 500 and fix the test assertions accordingly to test for a 500 status code.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestContext;
import javax.ws.rs.container.ContainerRequestFilter;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

import org.glassfish.jersey.filter.LoggingFilter;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerProperties;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

/**
 * Stack Overflow question http://stackoverflow.com/q/36878817/2587435
 * 
 * Run this like any other JUnit test. Only one required test dependency
 * 
 *  <dependency>
 *      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
 *      <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-inmemory</artifactId>
 *      <version>${jersey2.version}</version>
 *  </dependency>
 *
 * @author Paul Samsotha
 */
public class DynamicSubresourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @NameBinding
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
    public static @interface Status1000 {}

    @Provider
    @Status1000
    public static class Status1000Filter implements ContainerRequestFilter {
        @Override
        public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) throws IOException {
            context.abortWith(Response.status(500).build());
        }
    }

    @Path("v1")
    public static class V1Resource {

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return "v1";
        }

        @Path("sub")
        public V1SubResource getSub() {
            return new V1SubResource();
        }

        public static class V1SubResource {
            @GET
            public String get() {
                return "v1subresource";
            }
        }
    }

    @Path("v2")
    @Status1000
    public static class V2Resource {

        @GET
        public String get() {
            return "v2";
        }

        @Path("sub")
        public V2SubResource getSub() {
            return new V2SubResource();
        }

        @Status1000
        public static class V2SubResource {
            @GET
            public String get() {
                return "v2subresource";
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceConfig configure() {
        return new ResourceConfig(V1Resource.class, V2Resource.class)
                .property(ServerProperties.WADL_FEATURE_DISABLE, true)
                .register(Status1000Filter.class)
                .register(new LoggingFilter(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), true));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_1000_for_v2_resource_method() {
        final Response response = target("v2").request().get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(500));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_1000_for_v2_subresource_locator() {
        final Response response = target("v2/sub").request().get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(500));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_data_for_v1_resource_method() {
        final Response response = target("v1").request().get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), is("v1"));
    }

    @Test
    public void should_return_data_for_v1_subresource_locator() {
        final Response response = target("v1/sub").request().get();
        assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(200));
        assertThat(response.readEntity(String.class), is("v1subresource"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @peeskillet. This answers my question.

Comment: Unfortunately, Name Binding is not a good fit for us because this filter is **required** for a set of current and future resources. So I cannot expect developers writing future resources to know/remember and annotate those resources and sub-resources. Therefore, will go with a global filter that will have a check inside `filter` method to exclude resources that don't require this filter applied. This is a less desirable solution because the checking condition will be executed on every request.

Comment: I have the same issue as Jane, and agree that this workaround is far from ideal. Is there any other workaround as of now?